# Sum negative integer gives wrong result

Tags: mysql

My SUM with condition that has negative integer makes a wrong calculation.

If CN (creditnote) is true then total of that row must be set negative and then SUM the totals together.

```
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| id | CN    | date       | total |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| 1  | false | 2019-01-01 | 30    |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| 2  | true  | 2019-01-01 | 15    |
+----+-------+------------+-------+

SELECT 
  MONTH(invoices.date) as month,
  IF(invoices.CN = true,
    CAST(SUM(DISTINCT COALESCE(invoices.total * -1, 0)) AS SIGNED),
    CAST(SUM(DISTINCT COALESCE(invoices.total, 0)) AS SIGNED)) AS total,
  from invoices
  GROUP BY month
```

Result

```
+-------+------+
| month | total|
+-------+------+
| 1     | -30  |
+-------+------+
```

What I expect: 30 + (-15) = 15

```
+-------+------+
| month | total|
+-------+------+
| 1     |  15  |
+-------+------+
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `CN` appears in a month level summary?  And why is the value `false`, since it also appeared as `true` for the other record?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that was for debugging purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is on track for what you have in mind:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(date) AS month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CN = 'true' THEN -1.0 * total ELSE total END) AS total
FROM invoices
GROUP BY
    MONTH(date);
```

I say this is close, because it is not clear how or why `CN` is ending up in the aggregated result.  It makes sense to me, to report only the month and the total.

Comment: "because it is not clear how or why CN is ending up in the aggregated result" It seams in the expected results that `CN` is `true` for negative `total` output and false for positive `total` number?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Um...we started off with two rows, with two values for `CN`, and we ended up with a single value.  Maybe this is clear to you, but it's not to me :P

Comment: Nicked your idea

Comment: "Um...we started off with two rows, with two values for CN, and we ended up with a single value. Maybe this is clear to you, but it's not to me :P" well the topicstarter removed the confusion about the CN column after his edit.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Do you like using double quotes?  Anyway, it seems the OP has removed this from the result set now.

Comment: Well the qoutes makes it clear about what part off a comment iám commenting about.. yes indeed that is what i meant with the topicstarter removed the confusion about the CN column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just had to remove the SUM function from my total. How it can Sum the total without having a sum?

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers Either of the answers given here is along the lines of what you should be using.  The `SUM` function is what you should be using to sum across a group of records.

Answer (score 4):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (cn TINYINT, total INT);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (false,30),(true,15);    

SELECT SUM((0.5-cn)*2*total)x FROM my_table;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 15.0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is really a wicked answer +1.  Never would think of this.

Comment: How can you subtract from a boolean :0 ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I thought I nicked it off you !?! Must have been Paul - the other 'ieg' guy

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers Strawberry is assuming that you are using 0 and 1 to represent false and true.  This might be a `BIT` or `INT` column, but in any case, it is a fairly compact way of doing it, more compact than using the literal strings `true` and `false`.  With that out of the way, hopefully this answer makes sense to you.